# sql server, How to create a key with duplicated values

Tags: sql, rbac

I'm creating a model for RBAC on sql server. I have my table for permissions and another for roles. My doubt is, how can I make the role a key with duplicated values.

This is a fragment:

```
CREATE TABLE  permissions (permission int NOT NULL, name varchar(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (permission))
INSERT INTO permissions (permission, name) VALUES (1, 'createUser')
INSERT INTO permissions (permission, name) VALUES (2, 'deleteUser')
INSERT INTO permissions (permission, name) VALUES (4, 'editUserInfo')
INSERT INTO permissions (permission, name) VALUES (8, 'grantPermissions')

CREATE TABLE  roles (role varchar(50) NOT NULL, permission int NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (permission) REFERENCES permissions(permission))

INSERT INTO roles (role, permission) VALUES ('admin', 1)
INSERT INTO roles (role, permission) VALUES ('admin', 2)
INSERT INTO roles (role, permission) VALUES ('admin', 4)
INSERT INTO roles (role, permission) VALUES ('admin', 8)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a composite primary key?  `primary key (role, permission)`

Comment: I tried that. The result was not what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @antonio then explain what is actually what you need. Making 'permission' the Key seems an awful idea. Key should be a unique identifier. You may create index in the 'permission' field for performance though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't and don't want to do that.  Your `roles` table should have 1 row per role.  But then you add a 3rd table that serves as a mapping between your `roles` and `permissions` tables.

Something like this:

> roles <----> role_permission_mappings <----> permissions

So your `roles` table's key would be `role`.
And your `role_permission_mappings` table's key would be `(role,permission)`.

**EDIT**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/626b4/2) for an example of what this may look like.

Comment: This will allow you to store attributes of the role in the role table (like name, description, date created, date last changed, etc..) and permission attributes in the permission table (name, description, etc). You will then also be able to store attributes of the role-permission RELATIONSHIP in the role_permission_mappings table (like date created, description of the relationship, reason, or whatever..)

Comment: I understand the point of both of you sstan, JNevil but do you have a basic sample of role_permission_mappings. Thanks

Comment: @antonio: I edited my answer with a SQLFiddle link for a sample of the way it could be structured.